# Como imprimir o valor de um button em uma caixa de texto usando javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um calculadora em JavaScript e quero que ao clicar em um botão o valor seja exibido na tela. Outra dúvida é como eu faço par concatenar  o nome do `id` do `button` com o índice do `for` para eu adicionara um evento a cada `button`.

```js
var valor = [10];
//Aqui são armzenados os valores do button
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  valor[i] = document.getElementById('b' + (i + 1)).value;
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  b + i.addEventListener('click', function() {

  });
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="b1" value="1">1</button>
<button id="b2" value="2">2</button>
<button id="b3" value="3">3</button><br>
<button id="b4" value="4">4</button>
<button id="b5" value="5">5</button>
<button id="b6" value="6">6</button><br>
<button id="b7" value="7">7</button>
<button id="b8" value="8">8</button>
<button id="b9" value="9">9</button><br>
<button id="b10" value="0">0</button>
<button id="b11">+</button>
<button id="b12">-</button><br>
<button id="b13">/</button>
<button id="b14">x</button>
<button id="b15">=</button><br><br>
<input type="text" name="result" id="resultado">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema do teu código é esse trecho `b+i.addEventListener`, você está tentando concatenar uma variável que não existe `b`, com o valor de `i` e tentando adicionar um evento "nisto". Você precisa pegar o elemento que deseja adicionar o evento, `document.getElementById(  )` e passar o id como parâmetro que seria `'b'+i`. Segue código abaixo:

```js
var result = document.getElementById('resultado')
var valor = [];
  //Aqui são armzenados os valores do button
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    valor[i] = document.getElementById('b'+ i).value;
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.getElementById('b'+i).addEventListener ('click', function () {
      result.value = this.value;
    });
  }
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
input {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="b1" value="1">1</button>
<button id="b2" value="2">2</button>
<button id="b3" value="3">3</button><br>
<button id="b4" value="4">4</button>
<button id="b5" value="5">5</button>
<button id="b6" value="6">6</button><br>
<button id="b7" value="7">7</button>
<button id="b8" value="8">8</button>
<button id="b9" value="9">9</button><br>
<button id="b10" value="0">0</button>
<button id="b11">+</button>
<button id="b12">-</button><br>
<button id="b13">/</button>
<button id="b14">x</button>
<button id="b15">=</button><br><br>
<input type="text" name="result" id="resultado">
```